# R - How to selectively copy long format case responses to future years?

Tags: r

I am conducting a longitudinal analysis with data in long format. I have personality (O, C, E, A, N) measured in 2005, 2009 and 2013 with my dependent variable (job satisfaction) measured every year. Each person has their own ID. I have two goals (which *I think* might be able to be achieved with the same underlying logic):

1) I need another variable (column) indicating the first year that personality was measured for each person. If personality was never measured, then return NA. For example, if personality was first measured in 2009, then “2009” needs to be returned in this column for every row for that ID.

2) I need another variable (column) which copies the personality item responses for each year for each ID, unless it is replaced by a later measurement year (i.e. 2009, 2013). For example, if an ID completed the personality test in 2005 and 2009, then I need their responses for 2005 copied to years 2006, 2007, and 2008, but not 2009, as later entries (if they exist) should then become what gets copied forward to future years.

I have tried making a function for these, but ultimately failed.

I hope that makes sense. Extract of 100 cases below:

```
structure(list(Person_ID = c(100003L, 100003L, 100003L, 100003L, 
100003L, 100003L, 100003L, 100003L, 100003L, 100003L, 100005L, 
100005L, 100005L, 100005L, 100005L, 100005L, 100005L, 100005L, 
100005L, 100006L, 100006L, 100006L, 100006L, 100006L, 100006L, 
100006L, 100006L, 100007L, 100007L, 100007L, 100007L, 100007L, 
100008L, 100008L, 100008L, 100009L, 100009L, 100010L, 100010L, 
100010L, 100010L, 100010L, 100010L, 100010L, 100010L, 100010L, 
100010L, 100011L, 100011L, 100011L, 100011L, 100011L, 100014L, 
100014L, 100014L, 100014L, 100014L, 100014L, 100014L, 100014L, 
100014L, 100014L, 100015L, 100015L, 100015L, 100015L, 100015L, 
100015L, 100015L, 100015L, 100015L, 100015L, 100016L, 100016L, 
100016L, 100016L, 100016L, 100016L, 100016L, 100016L, 100016L, 
100016L, 100018L, 100018L, 100018L, 100018L, 100018L, 100018L, 
100018L, 100018L, 100018L, 100018L, 100019L, 100019L, 100019L, 
100019L, 100019L, 100019L, 100019L, 100019L), Job_Satisfaction = c(0L, 
NA, 7L, NA, 8L, 10L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 6L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 7L, NA, 9L, 3L, NA, 10L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 
NA, NA, NA, 8L, NA, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, NA, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L), Year = c(2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2005L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2005L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2006L, 2007L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L), O = c(5, NA, NA, NA, 
5.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
4.83333333333333, NA, 4.16666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 3.5, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.83333333333333, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 
NA, NA, 5.16666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
5.5, NA, NA, NA, 5.16666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 4.5, NA, 
NA, NA, 4.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 3.16666666666667, 
NA, NA, NA, 3.16666666666667, NA, 5.5, NA, NA, NA, 5.66666666666667, 
NA, NA, NA, 5.33333333333333, NA, 5.5, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 
NA), C = c(4.66666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 6.83333333333333, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.33333333333333, 
NA, 4.16666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 4.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 5.83333333333333, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.66666666666667, 
NA, NA, NA, 6.66666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 6.66666666666667, NA, 
6.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.83333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 
6, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, 6.66666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 6.5, NA, 
NA, NA, 6.5, NA, 5.5, NA, NA, NA, 5.83333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 
5.16666666666667, NA, 5.5, NA, NA, NA, 5.66666666666667, NA, 
NA, NA, 5.16666666666667, NA, 5.66666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 6, 
NA, NA, NA), E = c(4.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 5.16666666666667, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.66666666666667, 
NA, 4.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 3.83333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.5, NA, NA, NA, 
5.16666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 5.33333333333333, NA, 6.16666666666667, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.83333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 4.83333333333333, 
NA, NA, NA, 4.5, NA, 4.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 4.66666666666667, 
NA, NA, NA, 3.83333333333333, NA, 3.5, NA, NA, NA, 3.5, NA, NA, 
NA, 5.16666666666667, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3.16666666666667, NA, 
NA, NA, 2.66666666666667, NA, 2.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 2.5, 
NA, NA, NA), A = c(6.75, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.75, NA, 4.75, NA, NA, NA, 5, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 4.75, 
NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 5.25, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.5, NA, NA, NA, 5, 
NA, NA, NA, 5.5, NA, 6.75, NA, NA, NA, 5.75, NA, NA, NA, 6.75, 
NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 3.5, NA, NA, NA, 4.75, NA, 5.75, NA, NA, NA, 
5.75, NA, NA, NA, 5.5, NA, 5.75, NA, NA, NA, 5.75, NA, NA, NA
), N = c(3.16666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 3.33333333333333, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.66666666666667, 
NA, 4.5, NA, NA, NA, 4.16666666666667, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2.66666666666667, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.66666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 
2.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 3.16666666666667, NA, 1.83333333333333, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 2.83333333333333, 
NA, NA, NA, 1.83333333333333, NA, 3.83333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 
3, NA, NA, NA, 3.33333333333333, NA, 1.66666666666667, NA, NA, 
NA, 2.5, NA, NA, NA, 2.5, NA, 3.83333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 3.33333333333333, 
NA, NA, NA, 4.16666666666667, NA, 3.83333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 
4.5, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Person_ID", "Job_Satisfaction", 
"Year", "O", "C", "E", "A", "N"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a series of loops to do what I needed. Using the trait of "O" as an example:

```
df$PersonalityYear <- ifelse(df$Year=="2005",
                    "2005",
                    ifelse(df$Year=="2009",
                      "2009",
                      ifelse(df$Year=="2013",
                        "2013",
                        "No")))

#Code to solve the second goal.
df$MostRecentYear <- NA
n <- nrow(df)
for (i in 2:n) df$MostRecentYear[i] <- ifelse(df$PersonalityYear[i]=="2013",
                                          2013,
                                          ifelse(df$PersonalityYear[i]=="2009",
                                            2009,
                                            ifelse(df$PersonalityYear[i]=="2005",
                                              2005,
                                              ifelse(df$Person_ID[i]==df$Person_ID[i-1],
                                                df$MostRecentYear[i-1],
                                                NA))))

df$MostRecentO <- df$O
for (i in 2:n) df$MostRecentO[i] <- ifelse(is.na(df$MostRecentYear[i]),
                                        NA,
                                            ifelse(df$MostRecentYear[i]==df$PersonalityYear[i],
                                              df$O[i],
                                              df$MostRecentO[i-1]))

#Code to solve the first goal.
df$FirstYear <- NA
for (i in 2:n) df$FirstYear[i] <- ifelse(df$Person_ID[i]==df$Person_ID[i-1],
                                        ifelse(is.na(df$MostRecentYear[i-1]),
                                          df$MostRecentYear[i],
                                          df$FirstYear[i-1]),
                                      df$MostRecentYear[i])

df$FirstYearO <- df$O
for (i in 2:n) df$FirstYearO[i] <- ifelse(is.na(df$FirstYear[i]),
                                        NA,
                                        ifelse(df$FirstYear[i]==df$PersonalityYear[i],
                                              df$O[i],
                                              df$FirstYearO[i-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
data %>% group_by(Person_ID) %>% 
         mutate(first_year=dplyr::first(Year[!is.na(O)])) %>%   #return first year where O is not missing 
         mutate(O_fill=na.locf(O, na.rm = FALSE)) %>%  #using zoo::na.locf to replace NA's with non-NA prior to it
         head(n=20)

# A tibble: 20 x 10
  # Groups:   Person_ID [3]
  Person_ID Job_Satisfaction  Year     O     C     E     A     N first_year O_fill
  <int>            <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <int>  <dbl>
  1    100003                0  2005  5     4.67  4.33  6.75  3.17       2005   5   
  2    100003               NA  2006 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA          2005   5   
  3    100003                7  2007 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA          2005   5   
  4    100003               NA  2008 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA          2005   5   
  5    100003                8  2009  5.5   6.83  5.17  7     3.33       2005   5.5 
  6    100003               10  2010 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA          2005   5.5 
  7    100003               NA  2011 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA          2005   5.5 
  8    100003               NA  2012 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA          2005   5.5 
  9    100003               NA  2013 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA          2005   5.5 
  10    100003               NA  2014 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA          2005   5.5 
  11    100005                9  2005 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA            NA  NA   
  12    100005               NA  2007 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA            NA  NA   
  13    100005               NA  2008 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA            NA  NA   
  14    100005               NA  2009 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA            NA  NA   
  15    100005               NA  2010 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA            NA  NA   
  16    100005               NA  2011 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA            NA  NA   
  17    100005               NA  2012 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA            NA  NA   
  18    100005               NA  2013 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA            NA  NA   
  19    100005               NA  2014 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA            NA  NA   
  20    100006                6  2005  4.83  4.33  4.67  5.75  3.67       2005   4.83
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, though, this does not appear to reset the data in 'first_year' or 'O_fill' for a new ID.

Comment: @aspark2020 as you can see above, it works for me. Probably you have a name collision between `dplyr` and `plyr` in `group_by` verb, try loading `dplyr` and `zoo` in a fresh R session or call `group_by` directly using `dplyr::group_by`.